# How do I find the category an entry belongs to?

Tags: entries, categories, relations

I have a channel with entries which have a category field which is required.
When the entries are listed on a page how do I find the category that it belongs to?

```
{% for entry in entries %}
    <span class="event">{{ entry.title }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

Code so far is above.

The category has a background color field which I want to apply to the `<span>`.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm following you, you've got a category group setup with a color field on its field layout.

Then you've got a category field setup with it's source set to that category group and in an entry, you want to get to the color field on the category group.

```
{% for entry in entries %}

    {# Grab the first category #}
    {% set category = entry.categoryFieldHandle.first() %}

    {# 
        Or if there are multiple categories...
        set category = entry.categoryFieldHandle.find()
        And loop through to find the one you want
    #}

    <span class="event" style="background-color: {{ category.colorFieldHandle }}">{{ entry.title }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```